# LNK2005 errors despite matching runtime library (/MD)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++-cli, clr, msvcrt, lnk2005

I am attempting to use the [OFELI](http://ofeli.net/download.html) library in a CLI/C++ solution containing both C# and C++ projects, under VS2010. In short, the UI is written in WPF, and computations are done in CLR-enabled C++.

I downloaded the [OFELI](http://ofeli.net/download.html) source, converted the solution to VS2010 format, and was able to successfully build the static lib. However, upon linking to the lib (ofeli-debug.lib) a slew of LNK2005 errors result;

```
error LNK2005: "private: static class std::locale::_Locimp * __cdecl std::locale::_Getgloballocale(void)" (?_Getgloballocale@locale@std@@CAPAV_Locimp@12@XZ) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll)
```

I took care to insure that the lib was built with the /MDd setting, just as the project is. If I set the project to ignore msvcprtd.lib, I end up with a multitude of LNK2019 errors, as I'd expect.

Through experimentation, I've found that I can successfully link and use the ofeli lib from a non-CLR C++ test project, but not from a CLR enabled project (even if ofeli is compiled with CLR support enabled).

A simple code snippet which fails with many LNK2005 errors in my CLR project is below.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <OFELI.h>

using namespace OFELI;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Mesh(10, 1); // Instance an object from the OFELI namespace
    return 0;
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Change your project settings, use /clr instead of /clr:pure.

Comment: I am already using /clr, not /clr:pure.

Comment: Make sure that the /MDd option is applied to each of the cpp files. In my case, it was the cause of this error.